# Symfony Mobile detect redirection different twig

Tags: php, symfony, mobile, twig

I'm developing an application with Symfony now, i need to detect user support (desktop or mobile ) and redirect with the same controllers to different templates twig views (for desktop or for mobile).

I can't use media queries, for the HTML and CSS files, i have to different folders, one for desktop files and other for mobile files.

Comment: Ok ..... can you show us some code? What are you doing? What's the problem if any?

Comment: PHP is rendered serverside, no way to tell screen dimensions there. Mediaqueries are the way to go

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but its a big project, i don't know what can i show you exactly, my question is how can i work with the same controllers if the user is connected from desktop i will redirect him to files for desktop views like : index_desktop.html.twig and if he's connected from mobile i will redirect him to index_mobil.html.twig

Comment: You could use the clients user-agents and render other templates based on that

Comment: For example, you can create two different base templates (one for mobile users, one for desktop users). Then you can create a Twig extension offering a function that encapsulate the logic to determine which base template to use. You can then use this function in your child template to dynamically choose the parent template: `{% extends base_template() %}`

Comment: Thanks @xabbuh, i think its will be a good solution, but i don't have any idea about this twig extension can you help me ?

Comment: I suggest to start with the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html). It should cover the base mechanism to create a Twig extension and how to register in a Symfony application.

Comment: i would advise you to use media queries and make a design responsive

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't found a solution for your application, have you looked at [suncat/mobile-detect-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/suncat/mobile-detect-bundle)?  It has both PHP and Twig hooks.